# Is there any way to monitor ChromeOS updates?

Tags: google-chrome-os, chromebook

My chromebook has been acting up recently and it's always updating. I can't debug the issue because I can't tell if the issue is with the update or if I've narrowed the problem down. Is there any way to know when Google releases an update and what the changelog is?

Comment: You can always disable updates to debug the problem https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/chromebook-central/Ku8JeSOUd-U

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to know what is happening behind the scenes. Open up a terminal window and use command

`initctl stop update-engine`

to stop the update engine

`update_engine -foreground -logtostderr &`

to run the update engine in the foreground and while the above command is on

`while true; do update_engine_client -check_for_update; update_engine_client -update; pause 5; done`

to run the update, **please note that the above command is in single line**.

taken from here:
https://sites.google.com/site/cr48ite/getting-technical/force-update-chrome-os